# How to alter RubyGems Environment Variables (USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY and SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, environment

When trying to install a gem i receive an error:

```
No such device or address @ rb_file_s_stat - Z:/
```

when checking the gem environment variables i get the following return:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SOME_FOLDER\Ruby\bin>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/SOME_FOLDER/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: Z:/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "C:/Program Files (x86)/SOME_FOLDER/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/SOME_FOLDER/Ruby/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: Z:/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Program Files (x86)/SOME_FOLDER/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\Windows\system32
     - C:\Windows
     - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
     - C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
     - C:\Users\rekenmt\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

the problem is clear: **USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY** and **SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY** are not valid paths (Z:/ disk does not exist.) the question therefore is:

*how do i change those variables to point to another path*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and running this in the command line fixed it for me.

```
SET HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Source here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#gem-commands-fails-if-home-maps-to-a-network-drive